# Tkinter Scale slider with float values doesn't work with locale of language that uses comma for floats

Tags: python, tkinter, locale

I have following code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import locale
from Tkinter import *
#locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'pl_PL')
master = tk.Tk()
w = tk.Scale(master, from_=0.05, to=0.1, resolution=0.01)
w.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

And the slider works like it should. It doesn't slide when I uncomment that line with locale setting. That is probably due to the fact, that `pl_PL` locale uses comma for float separation. This may be a bug. How can I work around it so I can have the locale set properly?

Comment: That's annoying. It's mentioned [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue10647), and they claim that it's resolved, but I get the same behaviour as you (using the `pl_PL.utf8` locale) on Python 2.6 and 3.6 with Tkinter.TkVersion 8.5

Comment: Actually there is [a message](https://bugs.python.org/issue12558#msg185927) in the linked thread at the bottom of the given link tells that, this bug still continues(at that time) and it's [because of tkinter](https://bugs.python.org/issue12558#msg197766).

Comment: Thanks, @Lafexlos. The suggested fix "if the locale uses comma decimal separators (or always) convert float values for those keys to ints" is rather drastic, and wouldn't be helpful here. I guess a tolerable alternative is to use a plain Scrollbar and add a Label to it to display the current value.

Comment: ...or maybe not. I can't figure out how to make a Scrollbar behave the way I want it to.

Comment: @Lafexlos I've figured out a workaround. It's not fantastic, but I guess it's better than nothing. ;)

Comment: I'm glad you like my code, mys149. I've just made a few minor improvements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a slightly clunky workaround for this bug, using some ideas & code from Bryan Oakley's answer to [Dynamically reformat tkinter scale value python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164610/dynamically-reformat-tkinter-scale-value-python-2-7), where Bryan shows how to replace the usual value display with a custom formatted display. Unfortunately, we need to do a little more work here because even when we create Scale with `showvalue=False` it *still* gets blocked by float numbers that contain commas, even though it's not even showing them!

The solution is to force the numbers to be integers. That's easy enough to do if the `to` and `from_` values are whole number multiples of `resolution`, as shown below.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'pl_PL.UTF8')

class NewScale(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **options):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        # Disable normal value display...
        options['showvalue'] = False
        # ... and use custom display instead
        options['command'] = self._on_scale

        # Set resolution to 1 and adjust to & from value 
        self.res = options.get('resolution', 1)
        from_ = int(options.get('from_', 0) / self.res)
        to = int(options.get('to', 100) / self.res)
        options.update({'resolution': 1, 'to': to, 'from_': from_})

        # This could be improved...
        if 'digits' in options:
            self.digits = ['digits']
            del options['digits']
        else:
            self.digits = 2

        self.scale = tk.Scale(self, **options)
        self.scale_label = tk.Label(self)
        orient = options.get('orient', tk.VERTICAL)
        if orient == tk.VERTICAL:
            side, fill = 'right', 'y'
        else:
            side, fill = 'top', 'x'
        self.scale.pack(side=side, fill=fill)
        self.scale_label.pack(side=side)

    def _on_scale(self, value):
        value = locale.atof(value) * self.res
        value = locale.format_string('%.*f', (self.digits, value))
        self.scale_label.configure(text=value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    master = tk.Tk()
    w = NewScale(master, from_=0.05, to=0.1, resolution=0.01)
    w.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
    master.mainloop()
```

This code has been tested on Python 2.6.6 and 3.6.0. To run it on Python 3, change `import Tkinter as tk` to `import tkinter as tk`.

The NewScale widget supports both `tk.VERTICAL` and `tk.HORIZONTAL` orientations, with `tk.VERTICAL` being the default (the same as the normalScale widget). Its support for the `digits` option is currently rather primitive.

---

Here are a couple of methods that make NewScale a little more useful:

```
def get(self):
    return self.scale.get() * self.res

def set(self, value):
    self.scale.set(int(0.5 + value / self.res))
```

To test those methods, change the calling code to:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    master = tk.Tk()
    w = NewScale(master, from_=0.05, to=0.1, resolution=0.01)
    w.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
    w.set(0.07)
    tk.Button(master, text='Print', command=lambda: print(w.get())).pack()
    master.mainloop()
```

And it's probably a Good Idea to round the adjusted `to` & `from_` values to the nearest integer, rather than truncating them. That can be done by changing their initializers to:

```
from_ = int(0.5 + options.get('from_', 0) / self.res)
to = int(0.5 + options.get('to', 100) / self.res)
```

Comment: Nice code indeed. I'm leaving some notes for future users: it's good to change arbitrary 2 digits to something like`self.digits = int(abs(log10(self.res)))`, also it's good to initialize display with `self._on_scale(str(from_))`.